# C# MySQL cs.Open(); A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception Error

Tags: c#, mysql

Suddenly Today MySQL da.Fill(ds); code prompt an error called "The given key was not present in the dictionary". After that I have updated my dot net framework to 4.6.1. and MySQL to 8.0.16.0.

Now I'm getting "A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception" Error in my cs.Open(); code. Here is my connection string. Please help me.

```
MySqlConnection cs = new MySqlConnection(@"Persist Security Info=True;Password=XXX;User ID=XXX;Initial Catalog=XXX;Data Source=XXX;Character Set=utf8");
```

Here is the complete inner exception details:

```
    System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException was unhandled
      HResult=-2146233087
      Message=A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
      Source=MySql.Data
      StackTrace:
           at MySql.Data.Common.Ssl.StartSSL(Stream& baseStream, Encoding encoding, String connectionString)
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
           at TGL_ERP.LogIn.LogIn_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Projects\TGL System\2 Latest\TGL ERP\LogIn.cs:line 72
           at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
           at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
           at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
      InnerException: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
           HResult=-2147467259
           Message=The message received was unexpected or badly formatted
           ErrorCode=-2147467259
           NativeErrorCode=-2146893018
           InnerException:
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're using a connection string that is intended for MySQL and not SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, it's for MySQL, it's worked yesterday for last 6 months. Suddenly not working today in my windows 11 pc.

Comment: So when it told you to look at the inner exception and you did that, what did that tell you?

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot here [link](https://snipboard.io/Puw5zQ.jpg). Kindly check is this information supports you?

Comment: That looks very much like a Microsoft SQL Server connection string.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, I thought so too but I'm aware that they added various things to Connector/Net to make it more like SqlClient, including support for "@" as a parameter prefix. I checked the relevant documentation and, for example, "Initial Catalog" is a supported alias for "Database".

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Kindly let me know how to fix this?

Comment: Add the full exception details as text, not an image: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I have updated my question with full exception details as text. Kindly help

Comment: You mentioned .NET 4.6.1. Which versions of .NET, Windows, and MySQL Server are you using? .NET 4.6.1 is now end-of-life (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/) so you should be using at least .NET 4.7.2 or 4.8. My guess is that your MySQL Server now requires TLS 1.2 but your client is too old to support it. MySql.Data 8.0.16 is also extremely old and out-of-date.